# Import everything from a package

Tags: go, package

I'm wondering if there is any way to import the full contents of a package so that I don't have to prefix calls to things in the package with a package name?

For example, is there a way to replace this:

```
import "fmt"
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, world")
}
```

with this:

```
import "fmt"
func main() {
    Println("Hello, world")
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Import declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations)
>
> If an explicit period (.) appears instead of a name, all the package's
>   exported identifiers declared in that package's package block will be
>   declared in the importing source file's file block and must be
>   accessed without a qualifier.

---

For example,

```
package main

import . "fmt"

func main() {
    Println("Hello, world")
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/xl7DIxxMlU5

Output:

```
Hello, world
```